# Data appears different after opening .xls file through a macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have extracted a file from a SAP system and saved it as spreadsheet with extension `.xls`.
I have another excel file which contains a macro to open the former:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "G:\Manufacturing\MFCOMMON\PLANNING\Production\GR 25 Implementation\PCDC Implementation\Kotakis\Quantity_Sap.XLS"
Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
        "G:\Manufacturing\MFCOMMON\PLANNING\Production\GR 25 Implementation\PCDC Implementation\Kotakis\Z6TB_KOTAKIS.XLS"
Windows("Containers flow GR10_GR25.xls").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

but when I run it some numbers change and appear different from what they should if I open the file manually, e.g. 
from -896 with manual to -896.000

How can i change that??

Comment: I can't seem to duplicate this problem. What XL version are you running? Do dates and times appear different too?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to select all and change the format in the .xls file from SAP (something like: Home > Cells – Format > Format Cells > Custom) each time data is exported or, once-off, change the format in your default template (by creating a new template and saving it in XLSTART), though that would then apply to all new workbooks created with the default.

Comment: Thanks for your answer i found the solution i opened it with Workbooks.OpenText command and it worked fined!!